# Printing the Alphabet in Assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm

I'm starting to delve into assembly programming; I'm using NASM as my assembler for a 64 bit Debian system. To get my feet wet, I started with a basic project - print the lowercase alphabet, one letter at a time, one letter per line.

Technically, I succeeded in this goal - but I'm not sure how. Here's my program:

```
section .data
    newline: db 0x0A
    outlength: db 0x00

section .bss ; variables
    output:     resb 1

section .text ;main function
    global _start


_start:
    mov word [output],0x61

_loop:
    call _write
    mov eax, [output]
    inc eax
    mov [output],eax
    cmp eax, 0x7B
    jne _loop;

    mov eax,1
    mov ebx,0
    int 80h

_write:
    mov eax,4
    mov ebx,1
    mov edx,outlength
    mov ecx,newline
    int 80h
    ret
```

This program produces the following output:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
k
l
m
n
o
p
q
r
s
t
u
v
w
x
y
z
```

It's hard to show here, but there's a additional newline before the first line, and my bash prompt shows up immediately after the z character (on the same line). How is this output being produced? `output` doubles as both the character to be written, as well as the counter for the loop; and `newline` is a reserved byte that contains the newline character itself. There are two unresolved issues I can't figure out about this:

**1. My output length is 0 - how is anything ever being printed?**

**2. I'm only ever moving `newline` into the output register - so how is the data in `output` being used?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see a number of errors in your code:

```
mov word [output],0x61
```

This is incorrect because you only reserved a single byte of space for `output`. Use `mov byte [output],0x61` instead.

---

```
mov eax, [output]
inc eax
mov [output],eax
```

This is incorrect for the same reason. `output` is a single byte, not a `dword`. You can simply use `inc byte [output]` (and then `cmp byte [output],0x7B`).

---

```
mov edx,outlength
```

This places the address of `outlength` in `edx`, not its value (see [NASM Requires Square Brackets For Memory References](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc2.html#section-2.2.2)).
You want `movzx edx, byte [outlength]`. Or you could use `mov edx, [outlength]` if you change the declaration from `db` to `dd`.

---

Now to answer your questions:

> 1. My output length is 0 - how is anything ever being printed?

It isn't 0, as explained above.

> 2. I'm only ever moving newline into the output register - so how is the data in output being used?

Since you set `edx` to a "random" value, you might end up printing a lot of characters (some of which might not be visible). So it's not unplausible that `sys_write` ends up printing the character that you've stored at `output`.

Comment: Instead of loading `outlength` from memory, it would be even better to just declare it as an assembler constant with `outlength equ 1`, so you can use `mov edx, outlength` to set edx = 1.

Comment: That was it - fixing those bugs got me the desired behavior exactly (no weird/missing newlines) and makes a whole lot more sense than what I had. I guess starting out, it's easy to mistake all the various assembly commands for each other. If only there was a way to write code in a more readable format, and then have it translated to assembly automatically.... :) Thanks!